# why vi can modify a file while this file is write locked?

Tags: unix, locking

I compile this file and run it in one console.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
                /* l_type   l_whence  l_start  l_len  l_pid   */
    struct flock fl = {F_WRLCK, SEEK_SET,   0,      0,     0 };
    int fd;

    fl.l_pid = getpid();

    if (argc > 1) 
        fl.l_type = F_RDLCK;

    if ((fd = open("lockdemo.c", O_RDWR)) == -1) {
        perror("open");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Press <RETURN> to try to get lock: ");
    getchar();
    printf("Trying to get lock...");

    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &fl) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("got lock\n");
    printf("Press <RETURN> to release lock: ");
    getchar();

    fl.l_type = F_UNLCK;  /* set to unlock same region */

    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Unlocked.\n");

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
ZJ:~/Documents/c$ ./a.out
press <RETURN> to try to get lock: 
Trying to get lock...got lock
press <RETURN> to release lock:
```

I open another console and vi lockdemo.c and had modified lockdemo.c successfully. Why? Isn't this file locked?
While I open another console

```
ZJ:~/Documents/c$ ./a.out
press <RETURN> to try to get lock:
```

the a.out was always running getchar(), and cannot even execute printf("Trying to get lock...");
I am totally confused.

Comment: There are three different locking mechanisms available on some systems, two of which are specified by POSIX. There is fcntl and lockf, though the latter is relatively new still, and in the case of at least Linux, there is also a flock function. All of them are advisory of course. Locking a file really doesn't mean a thing it seems. And if another process uses another locking function, there is no guarantee that your process will necessarily be safe to read/write to the file. In the case of mandatory locks, they are still unreliable on Linux (see [BUGS](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are applying an **advisory** lock on the `lockdemo.c` file. `vi` is free to ignore it by design. You should have used a **mandatory** lock which AFAIK isn't standardized under Unix to enforce `vi` not to do it.

Comment: What is the point of advisory lock if a file cannot be protected from modification?

Comment: Let's say the same point as traffic lights which are not better protected from crossing when red.

Comment: I think @jlliagre makes a good point: Red traffic lights do nothing to prevent a car from crossing the intersection, yet we trust them with our lives.  This is a real-life example of an advisory lock.